# No aparece secure boot en HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 v2 (P78) Servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

tengo una maquina HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 v2 (P78) Servers Linux, pero necesito desactivar secure boot, pero en la bios no aparece la opcion, como la desactivo o como habilito esa opcion?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.